# Stop Animation Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a side menu that appears and disappears when you hover over each item. But when I click on an item, I want the animation to stop.

**this is the animation on mouseover**

```
$('#navigation > li').hover(
    function() {
        $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-7px'},200);
    },
    function () {
        $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({'marginLeft':'-150px'},200);
    }
);
```

**this is animation at the click of a single item**

```
$("#navigation > li").click(function(){
       $('a',$(this)).stop();
});
```

Comment: can you submit a fiddle ?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem but I recommend you to use `$('a', this)` instead of `$('a', $(this))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$("#navigation > li").click(function(){
   $(this).children('a').stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/XTpfJ/)**

This will unbind the hover event

```
$("#navigation > li").click(function()
 {
  $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
 });
});
```

Hope this helps